# Função retornando NaN

Tags: javascript, funções

Bom estou tentando executar esta função e resulta em NaN, não consta nem um erro no console.

```
var numeros = [10,2,5,,30,25,19,20,50,40,150]

function media(nums) {
    var tam = nums.lenght
    var soma = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        soma += nums[i]
    }

    return Math.round(soma/tam)
}

document.write(media(numeros))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dois erros: ‘length’ está escrito incorretamente (atribuído à ‘tam’), e um valor não numérico no vetor ‘numeros’ (onde contém duas vírgulas).

Devendo ficar:

```
var numeros = [10,2,5,30,25,19,20,50,40,150]

function media(nums) {
  var tam = nums.length
  var soma = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
      soma += nums[i]
  }

  return Math.round(soma/tam)
}

document.write(media(numeros))
```